# Subsets with finite boundary on the complex plane

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Suppose that $B$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$, also suppose that $\partial B$ is finite (i.e., the boundary of $B$ is a finite set). From this  can I conclude that $B$ is finite?

My attempt was the following:

- $\mbox{int}(B)=\emptyset$, then $\partial B=\overline{B}\setminus\mbox{int}(B)=\overline{B}\setminus\emptyset=\overline{B}$, from this $\overline{B}$ is finite and therefore $B$ is finite.
- $\mbox{int}(B)\not=\emptyset$, then there exists $x\in \mbox{int}(B)$, so there is $\delta>0$ such that $B(x, \delta)\subset B$, I don't know what I can conclude from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this.  Assume $\operatorname{int} B \ne \varnothing$ and $B$ is bounded.  WLOG assume $0 \in \operatorname{int}B$.  Fix $\theta \in [0,2\pi)$ and consider the half-line $\{r e^{i\theta}\;|\;r > 0\}$.  Since $r e^{i\theta} \in B$ for $r$ close enough to $0$ and $r e^{i\theta} \not\in B$ for $r$ large enough, there must exist $r_\theta > 0$ with $r_\theta e^{i\theta} \in \partial B$. (Say $r_\theta = \inf \{r>0\;:\;r e^{i\theta} \not\in B\}$.) Thus $\partial B$ is infinite; in fact, uncountable.

Comment: The structure of the complex plane was fundamental in its argument, since the result is not valid, for example, in $\mathbb{R}$. Excellent idea, thank you very much.